# Dynamic form fields should not have same value in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-request, laravel-form

I'm implementing a form with dynamic fields being added by an add field button. What I need is to prevent some of these fields to have the same value before submission.

Currently my Request rules look like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'myfield.*.domain' => 'required|url',
        'myfield.*.group' => 'required',
        'myfield.*.client' => 'nullable'
    ];
}
```

For instance, what if want the domain input to be unique in the form submission (not the database)? Is this possible?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Adding 'distinct' rule did the job for the specific field.

```
'myfield.*.domain' => 'required|url|distinct'
```

The validation errors though **sometimes** don't show up at my view. Testing the same input errors on purpose, the error messages sometimes show up as they should and sometimes `$errors->all()` returns an empty array.

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <div class="card-panel red white-text alert">
        <span>{{ $error }}</span>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Its doable but not fail proof, you'll need to use javascript to do the client side validation. A user can always disable js entirely or manipulate the dom via the web inspector.

Comment: Thanks @DigitalDrifter I use frontend validation but I want to implement backend validation too to make it more strict and safe

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to achieve what you ask:

First, and more easy, use an after validation on your form request:

```
public function withValidator($validator){
  $validator->after(function ($validator) {
     $domain = $this->domain;
     if($this->group == $domain || $this->client == $domain){
        $validator->errors()->add('Domain', 'Domain must be unique in form');
     }
  }
}
```

Second and more reusable way is to create your own custom rule, [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules) is the official docs to do that.

Comment: Thanks @JoseSilva, adding 'distinct' rule was enough for the validation to work. I edited my thread with the new rule.